# Form onsubmit doesn't work with form .submit()

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form and I have applied a function onsubmit:

```
var theForm = document.getElementById("myform");
theForm.onsubmit = function FormSubmit() {
alert("something");
};
```

I have added in my form a submit button `<input type="submit" value="submit"/>`

The `something` text is alerted. Great!

I have an image and I want to make it to submit the form:

```
<img onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();" src="mylocation"/>
```

But it doesn't make the function... it doesn't alert `something` on screen.

**EDIT:** I don't want something with jQuery. Pure JS

Comment: Event handlers are only run in response to user interactions, not other script actions.

Comment: type="submit value="submit" maybe you should close submit with a "

Comment: @Déjàvu edited post right now - my write mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is event handlers doesn't respond when the event called by script.

Say like bellow

```
  var theForm = document.getElementById("myform");
  function FormSubmit() {
    alert("something");
  };
  theForm.onsubmit = FormSubmit;
```

And call manually the function `onclick` of image like bellow

```
<img onclick="FormSubmit();document.getElementById('myform').submit();" src="mylocation"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Event handlers are only run in response to user actions or asynchronous events, not normal program actions like calling `form.submit()`. One reason for this is that it's not uncommon for the submit handler of a form to do some work and then call `form.submit()`, and this would cause an infinite recursion if it triggered the handler again.

Put the code you want to run in a named function:

```
function mySubmit() {
    alert("something");
}

theForm.onsubmit = function() {
    mySubmit();
};
```

Then you can call that function in your click handler:

```
<img onclick="mySubmit(); document.getElementById('myform').submit();" src="mylocation"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `a` tag around your image, something like this:

```
<a href="javascript://" onClick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();">
  <img src="mylocation" />
</a>
```